# Какие есть онлайн сервисы по проверки неиспользуемого css методом вставки html/css?

Tags: css

Какие есть онлайн сервисы по проверки неиспользуемого `css` методом вставки `html/css`?

Comment: https://gtmetrix.com/remove-unused-css.html

Comment: https://unused-css.com/

Answer (score 0):

Определить какой CSS не используется на странице вы можете при помощи Developer Tools в Хроме — [Console → Coverage](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#coverage).